# Importing huge Database into local server

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, xampp

Is there any way I can Import a huge database into my local server.

The database is of 1.9GB and importing it into my local is causing me a lot of problems.

I have tried sql dumping and was not successful in getting it in my local and have also tried changing the Php.ini settings.

Please let me know if there is any other way of getting this done.

I have used BigDump and also [Sql Dump Splitter](http://www.sqldumpsplitter.com/) but I am still to able to find a solution

Comment: Have you tried http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/?

Comment: What specifically are the problems you're running into, and more importantly, what exactly are you doing that's causing those problems? `mysqldump` can handle databases of virtually any size.

Comment: Just use the `mysql.exe` binary to import your dump: `mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#`

Comment: are your tables InnoDB or MYISAM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -u #username# -p #database# < #dump_file#
```

Answer (score 2):

- Navigate to your mysql bin directory and login to your mysql
- Select the database
- use source command to import the data

> ```
> [user@localhost] mysql -uroot -hlocalhost // assuming no password
> [user@localhost] use mydb // mydb is the databasename
> [user@localhost] source /home/user/datadump.sql
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Restoring a backup of that size is going to take a long time. There's some great advice here: http://vitobotta.com/smarter-faster-backups-restores-mysql-databases-with-mysqldump/ which essentially gives you some additional options you can use to speed up both the initial backup and the subsequent restore.